# how can i add a new property to an object

Tags: iphone

i have a custom imageView and i want to add a new prooerty "symbol" to it,so that i can identify every object of my custom imageView.So how can i add a new property to it?Should i go for tag?but i have many objects,so i have to set many tags.

Please help......

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to do it is to create a class that extend UIImageView, add a your variable, add the property and synthesize it.
Then if you are working with IB just change the class of you object, once added.